# Would you call this a drawer?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

In my closet I have shelves where I put my clothes but i have one with a door and a lock but its not like the drawers in my desk that I pull them out, its just a little door that opens and closes.
How would that be called? 
And is it called “shelves” where you put your clothes?

Comment: Could you add a pic?

Answer (score 1):

I would call that a cupboard. That's maybe quite broad; you could qualify by describing it like you've done. But I can't think of any word specifically referring to what you describe.

Comment: In American English, we only use *cupboard* for the kitchen cupboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're talking about in American English most likely would be just called a compartment with a door. And yes, those things that you put your clothes on are called shelves.

Answer (score 0):

I would call it a cabinet probably.